# Generalization of De Rham cohomology for spinor fields

Tags: homology-cohomology, spin-geometry

Is there a generalization of De Rham  cohomology for spinors fields?

I can see that one can construct p form fields out of spinor field by contraction of the type $\bar{\psi} \gamma^{a_1} \gamma^{a_2}...\gamma^{a_p}\chi$.

Now we can consider the integral of the p form fields on p-cycles.
There is a natural derivative like operation acting on spinor fields $\gamma \cdot \partial$. Does this map have the the desired properties to make a co-homology in some way.
If I cannot use this map can I use some other operator to suitably generalize the exterior derivative operator.

I have a background in physics and not in mathematics, please keep that in view when you write your answer.

Comment: Can you please transfer the question to physics stack exchange so I can try to provide you with an answer from a more physical point of view

Comment: @DavidBarMoshe I doubt that the question would be welcome on Physics SE, as too mathematical questions are often closed there.  But it can also be found [here](http://www.physicsoverflow.org/32072/generalization-of-de-rham-cohomology-for-spinor-fields), where answers from a physical point of view are appropriate.

Comment: @DavidBarMoshe Thanks for you interest. I posted it here. http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/190222/generalization-of-de-rham-cohomology-for-spinor-fields

Comment: Crossposted to http://mathoverflow.net/q/209604/13917

Comment: There is an answer at http://www.physicsoverflow.org/32072